# Conditional expression for '...' not working in function

Tags: r

I am trying to pass multiple `if-else` conditions in my function and so I am using `dots` because the function will take many arguments.

I am trying to return `yes` when the first element of `dots` is called as a list. For example (simple version):

```
testt <- function(...){
  ar <- list(...)
  val <- ar[[1]]
  if(is(val == 'list') == TRUE){
    print('yes')
  } else {print('no')}
}

test(list(1))
>[1] "no"
Warning message:
In if (is(val == "list") == TRUE) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It won't accept that `ar[[1]]` is a list, how can I work around this? additionaly, is the warning trying to tell me something as to why this is not working?

Comment: You are misusing `is`. Check the online help.

Comment: You need `if(is.list(val)){...}` or `if(is(var, 'list')){...}` or even `if(inherist(var, 'list')){...}`

Comment: `the first element of dots` there is a shortcut for that: `test <- function(...) if (inherits(..1, 'list')) 'yes' else 'no'` or `...elt(1)` if you need a programmatic approach

Comment: @rawr what does `..1` signify in your example? does 1 denote the position in the list?

Comment: @Limey I made a silly mistake, it does not take `==` in `is()`.

Comment: yes that's right, there is also `...elt()` which can be used dynamically

Comment: @rawr ah that' amazing! I really did not know that, as for `...elt()` can you provide an example of its usage? I will be using `...` alot and dynamically.

Comment: @rawr If i wanted to index specific element in the list, for example lets say that the first position in the list has elements three elements. Could I pick these in some way with `..1`?

Comment: this just refers to the dots, the third element of `...` and be indexed as a normal object `..3[[1]]` or equivalently `...elt(3)[[1]]` although if you are performing operations on all elements, it is easier to have one object `list(...)` and use `lapply`

Comment: @rawr Thank you for these options, they are incredibly helpful!